# Is there a way to use pdf images with the saveVideo function of R's animation package?

Tags: r, pdf, animation, ffmpeg

I've created a few MP4 files using the `saveVideo` function in the `animation` package, but the colours are relatively dull in one of them. I've compared the output of one of the images in the animation by producing a PNG and a PDF, with the colours in the PDF appearing much bolder. I was hoping to code the images as PDFs within the animation to see if it improves the output, but I am getting stuck with a message "Rplot.pdf: Invalid data found when processing input" and no MP4 being produced.

The internal code of the saveVideo function implies that PDF images can be used with the following:

```
num = ifelse(file.ext == "pdf", "", ani.options("imgnfmt"))
```

Here's a toy example that demonstrates the issue. This works fine:

```
library(animation)
saveVideo({
  darkcol = "#000000"
  par(bg = darkcol)
  ani.options(interval = 0.5)
  for (i in 1:10)
  {
    plot(0:10, runif(11, 4, 8), col = "magenta1")
    ani.pause()
  }
}, video.name = "TestVideo.mp4",
ani.res = 144, ani.height = 900, ani.width = 1600)
```

This one doesn't work:

```
library(animation)
saveVideo({
  pdf(ani.options("img.fmt"))
  darkcol = "#000000"
  par(bg = darkcol)
  ani.options(interval = 0.5)
  for (i in 1:10)
  {
    plot(0:10, runif(11, 4, 8), col = "magenta1")
    ani.pause()
  }
}, video.name = "TestVideoPDF.mp4",
ani.res = 144, ani.height = 9, ani.width = 16,
use.dev = FALSE, ani.type = "pdf")
```

Here is what the console displays when I run the second batch of code:

```
Executing: "ffmpeg" -y -framerate 2 -i Rplot.pdf -pix_fmt yuv420p TestVideoPDF.mp4
ffmpeg version 2023-04-06-git-b564ad8eac-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      58.  6.100 / 58.  6.100
libavcodec     60.  9.100 / 60.  9.100
libavformat    60.  4.101 / 60.  4.101
libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
libavfilter     9.  5.100 /  9.  5.100
libswscale      7.  2.100 /  7.  2.100
libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Rplot.pdf: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I'm on a Windows PC running Windows 10 Enterprise. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You  can do a PDF animation, not a video.